# Declaring a Class C++

Tags: c++, class

I am struggling knowing how to create a class. I want to create a "Player" class and all I want to do is pass in the name while I'll have the other variables start at 0 until they are updated when a game is run (later in the program)

```
Player::Player(string name_in)    
{
    name = name_in;
    int numOfWins = 0;
    int numOfLoses = 0;
    int numOfDraws = 0;
    int totalMatches = 0;
}
```

Right now there are lots of errors around numOfWins, numOfLoses, numOfDraws and totalMatches. What can I do to fix this?

Comment: What you have there is the constructor function of the class - you also need the class declaration.

Comment: And the errors are ...? In your code, everything except name is only declared locally in the constructor => It won´t exist outside of the {}

Comment: What do you mean, "lots of errors"? Can you give us a [minimal complete example](http://www.sscce.org)?

Comment: First of all you should take and read a good C++ introductory book. Also you should provide _complete_ sources, with Player class declaration etc. And last but not least, you should pass the `name_in` parameter by reference, and probably make in `const` (see the book!)

Comment: First change the line `name = name_in;` to `string name = name_in;`. Since the variable is missing the type in front of it, this will give an error. If you have any errors after that, show us the exact error and the code that we need to see.

Comment: Have you read http://www.cplusplus.com/doc/tutorial/?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should declare other instance variables in the class declaration, rather than declaring them as locals (which is completely useless).

```
// This part goes in the header
class Player {
    string name;
    int numOfWins;
    int numOfLoses;
    int numOfDraws;
    int totalMatches;
public:
    Player(string name_in);
};
```

Now in the constructor you could use initialization lists:

```
// This part goes into the CPP file
Player::Player(string name_in)
// Initialization list precedes the body of the constructor
: name(name_in), numOfWins(0), numOfLoses(0), numOfDraws(0), totalMatches(0) {
// In this case, the body of the constructor is empty;
// there are no local variable declarations here.
}
```

Comment: My confusion is what parts go in the .h file and what go into the .cpp file

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps the error is in your `int ...` part of assignments, which essentially creates a new local variable in a constructor.

Try this version:

```
#include <string>
using namespace std;

class Player
{
    string name;
    int numOfWins;
    int numOfLoses;
    int numOfDraws;
    int totalMatches;

public:
    Player(string name_in)    
    {
        name = name_in;
        numOfWins = 0;
        numOfLoses = 0;
        numOfDraws = 0;
        totalMatches = 0;
    }
};
```

Comment: My confusion is what parts go in the .h file and what go into the .cpp file

Comment: @K-Bake: declarations in `.h`, definitions in `.cpp`. See [dasblinkenlight's answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/22888118/1488799) for suggestion.

Answer (score 0):

The errors you get, at least from the snippet you posted are caused for you can't declare variables in constructor - you declare them in class body and initialize in constructor or using another function.

```
#include <string>

class Player {
public:
    Player( std::string const& name_in) : name( name_in),
                                          numOfWins(), numOfLoses(),
                                          numOfDraws(), totalMatches()
                                          {}  // constructor 
                                              // will initialize variables
                                              // numOfWins() means default 
                                              // initialization of an integer
private:
    std::string name;
    int numOfWins;
    int numOfLoses;
    int numOfDraws;
    int totalMatches;
};
```

usage:

```
int main() {
    Player( "player_one");
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Kinda vague, but I'll take a crack at it. You Probably want:

```
class Player{
    string name;    
    int numOfWins;
    int numOfLosses;
    int numOfDraws;
    int totalMatches;
    Player(string name_in)
};

Player::Player(string name_in){
    name = name_in;
    numOfWins = 0;
    numOfLosses = 0;
    numOfDraws = 0;
    totalMatches = 0;
}
```

Haven't used C++ in a while, so this may be faulty.